# Obscuring published items from the publishing queue

Tags: tridion

I have a Tridion implementation that is, in essence, multi-tennent. Different interest groups use the same environment. Security takes care that users cannot see publications/content from groups they are not permitted to see. However, in the publishing queue, all users can see the title of items that are in the queue; they cannot open the item but they can see the title (e.g. "Our company releases sky high profits!")

For sensitivity reasons I would like hide the title of the item when the queue list is loaded according to the scoped publications of the user viewing the queue. So, for example, If I am only able to work in publications b & c but not in a & d when the queue loads, I can see the titles of content coming from b & c but *not* a & d. I will see something like "Item from publication D".

Is this straight-forward to do with an extension and does any one have some examples of how to do this?

Comment: Can we assume you are talking about Tridion 2011?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic is the most complicated thing about it. You need to work out what the user can see or not.

This is a good candidate for a Data Extender to the CME. Filter out the items on the server before the response is returned. There is [a section](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_3B40E7C7F2334D9B9DAD12FA202EFAA7) of the online documentation dedicated to the topic, so that is hopefully enough to get you started.

A crafty person would still be able to access the information by directly querying the API / Core Service, but I imagine that is not a high priority in this case.

Comment: Maybe it'd make sense to remove the select user drop-down in the queue as well? Tenants probably shouldn't know about each other as well, or is that already hidden some other way?